# Unable to Delete Cells using JavaScript: The value provided (3) is outside the range

Tags: javascript

```
function selectTo(cell) {    
  var row = cell.parent();
  var cellIndex = cell.index();
  var rowIndex = row.index();
  var rowStart, rowEnd, cellStart, cellEnd;
  if (rowIndex < startRowIndex) {
    rowStart = rowIndex;
    rowEnd = startRowIndex;
    sessionStorage.setItem('rowStart', rowStart);
    sessionStorage.setItem('rowEnd', rowEnd);
  } else {
    rowStart = startRowIndex;
    rowEnd = rowIndex;
    sessionStorage.setItem('rowStart', rowStart);
    sessionStorage.setItem('rowEnd', rowEnd);
  }

  if (cellIndex < startCellIndex) {
    cellStart = cellIndex;
    cellEnd = startCellIndex;
    sessionStorage.setItem('cellStart', cellStart);
    sessionStorage.setItem('cellEnd', cellEnd);
  } else {
    cellStart = startCellIndex;
    cellEnd = cellIndex;
    sessionStorage.setItem('cellStart', cellStart);
    sessionStorage.setItem('cellEnd', cellEnd);
  }

  for (var i = rowStart; i <= rowEnd; i++) {
    var TableID = sessionStorage.getItem("TableID");
    var table6 = document.getElementById(TableID);
    var row6 = table6.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i];
    var rowCells = row6.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var j = cellStart; j <= cellEnd; j++) {
      rowCells[j].className = "hover";
    }
  }
}

var TableID = sessionStorage.getItem("TableID");
var cellStart = sessionStorage.getItem("cellStart");
var cellEnd = sessionStorage.getItem("cellEnd");
var rowStart = sessionStorage.getItem("rowStart");
var rowEnd = sessionStorage.getItem("rowEnd");

for (var i = rowStart; i <= rowEnd; i++) {
  var myTable = document.getElementById(TableID);
  var row10 = myTable.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i];
  var rowCells = row10.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var j = cellStart; j < cellEnd; j++) {
    if (j === cellStart && i === rowStart)
      continue;
    //rowCells[j].style.display = "none";
    myTable.rows[i].deleteCell(j);
  }
}
```

When I delete cells, use a different method `table.row[i].deleteCell(j);` or `removechild` I get `out of range` error.

mesage:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'deleteCell' on
>   'HTMLTableRowElement': The value provided (3) is outside the range [0,
>   3).
>       at init.callback

Comment: Please post the related HTML as well. Most likely, you are forgetting that indexes start at `0`.

Comment: Please post the **relevant** rendered Markup (not the code that generates the markup) So we can see why it might not be able to find the specified index. Also the values of `TableID`, `cellStart`, `cellEnd`,  `rowStart` and `rowEnd` are important to know alongside the markup.

Comment: I have function to delete cells (no problems) but when I'm use it for merge cells there are problem with the dom. I'm use javascript not Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution:

```
     var listHover = document.querySelectorAll('.hover');
                                for (var i = 0; i < listHover.length; i++) {
                                    if (i > 0) {
                                        listHover[i].style.display = 'none';
                                    }
                                }
```